# string matching for a magic __call method

Tags: php, regex, string, string-matching, magic-methods

I have a set of methods named like `getThing($what, $extra_args)` (**get** is always present in the name)

...and besides the normal way of calling them, I also want to be able to call them like:

- `getWhatThing()` => `return getThing($what, $extra_args);`
- `WhatThing()` => `echo getThing($what, $extra_args);`
- `Thing('what')` => `echo getThing('what', $extra_args);`
- if all these fail throw the *Method doesn't exist* error...

How can I do this from within `__call()` ? 
I know I should avoid magic methods, but I want to make life easier for the people who will use my API :)

Thanks

Comment: To satisfy my curiosity: how is it this makes your API *easier* for others?

Comment: Make life easier for the people who will use your API: don't implement this feature.

Comment: why do you say that? Isn't this what __call is for?

Comment: Really? Why you want to make your class that magic and scary? 4 invisible methods for the same functionality... `__call()` _may_ be used for something like this, but that doesn't mean, that you _must_ use it at any cost. There is no benefit against real methods.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a non sense..
All your methods should just `return $var`.

At that point if you want to echo it you need to excplicty do:

```
echo getThing();
```

Answer (score 0):

[The code in this comment on PHP.net's documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#103478) for __call should be a good starting point for you, but you'll need to add more matches to the switch section.

Comment: Now, whether you _should_ do this or not is up for debate. I'd say you should only do this if you are going to create and maintain your own thorough documentation. Remember that code-generated documentation will not list these functions.